# group by in sql

Tags: sql, select, group-by

Here i dont want to group by on amount and i also dont want to remove amount from select statement
so how to modify query

```
select min(id),userid,calcu.amount from usertable ut
inner join calcu co on  ut.userid=co.userid
group by userid,amount
```

how i modify above query ...

i try to achieved records which user have min id.. let say user have 1,2,3,4 id in calcu table now i want 1 id and against that there is amount column so i want that amount ..

when i remove amount i got 10 records but when i write amount column in select and group by i got 15 records

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i try to achieved records which user have min id.. let say user have 1,2,3,4 id in calcu table now i want 1 id and against that there is amount column so i want that amount

Comment: Is userid necessary?

Comment: yesss @ChesterLim

Comment: Which amount do you want to see if there is more than one different amount for given userid?

Comment: u might be able to achieve it using nested query. Where is id column from?

Comment: id and userid column is from usertable

Comment: yes how i done this through nested query ?

Comment: @nimdil the amount which have min id in calcu table ..

Comment: Please provide your sample data and desired output so we can help.

Comment: Do you use sql server or mysql or .....

Comment: @EidMorsy urgghh .. i mentioned sql .. then why you ask that irrelevant question

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using the following nested query.

```
 SELECT (SELECT MIN(ID),USERID FROM USERTABLE ut WHERE ut.USERID = co.USERID GROUP BY USERID), co.AMOUNT FROM CALCU co
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this please?  Your question is not very clear (pls post sample data and a table with desired output so I can test my query)

```
SELECT A.MINID, A.USERID, co.AMOUNT
FROM (SELECT MIN(id) AS MINID, USERID
      FROM usertable ut
      GROUP BY userid 
      ) A
INNER JOIN calcu co ON A.USERID=co.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

When you just select amount without grouping by it, a random row for each group will be selected (if your DBMS allows this at all).

In most DBMSs you have to specify which row for each group you want to display. This happens with aggregate functions. Choose the one that fits your needs

- max()
- min()
- avg()
- count()

---

If you want to see the row that corresponds to a row with a min()/max() value you can use one of these approaches (they are standard sql, so not limited to mysql): [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try something around these lines:

```
select calcu.id,ut.userid,calcu.amount 
from usertable ut
inner join 
(
   select id,userid,amount from calc where id in 
   (
        select min(id) from calc group by userid
   )
) calcu
on ut.userid = calcu.userid
```

Comment: That's assuming I understand your intentions correctly; I'm not 100% sure about this though